# delete data from database directly from interface using javafx

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

[image]

i wanted to delete data from my TableView directly from my GUI when i select the data i delete it by ID value it is showing an error telling me to cast to type **StudentData** or make an ObservableList both of them don't work. what am i doing wrong?

```
    public void Delete(ActionEvent event)
{
    try
    {
        Connection conn = SqliteConnection.Connector();
        StudentData data = (StudentData) studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Studentlist WHERE ID =?;");

        ps.setString(1, data.getID());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried the above code but still no result cannot delete the row i select from my GUI

Comment: add to your question the full stack trace of the error

Comment: You need to use an `if statement`. If the delete from the database is successful, then you need to remove the `StudentData` object from the observablelist. `yourObservableList.remove(data);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Delete(ActionEvent event)
{
    try
    {
        Connection conn = SqliteConnection.Connector();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Studentlist WHERE ID = ?");
        StudentData studentdata = studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        ps.setString(1, studentdata.getID());

        ps.execute();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

My guess is

Your data model class name is **StudentData**

Your TableView name is **studenttable**

so...the syntax is...

```
//to select tableview row
StudentData selectedrow = studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

//prepare query with blank ID to be filled with the value of the selected row
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Studentlist WHERE ID = ?");

//from the selected row getID only
ps.setString(1, selectedrow.getID());

//execute delete operation e.g DELETE FROM Studentlist WHERE ID = 123
ps.execute();
```

Note that TableView must take a StudentData as a type argument to avoid casting:

```
@FXML
private TableView<StudentData> studenttable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ID` column be a numeric type, e.g. integer, you should be binding a numeric Java type to the `?` placeholder, e.g.

```
Connection conn = SqliteConnection.Connector();
StudentData data = (StudentData) studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Studentlist WHERE ID = ?");
ps.setInt(1, data.getID());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

If `data.getID()` would return a `String`, then parse it into an integer using:

```
int theID = Integer.valueOf(data.getID());
```

and then bind this to your statement:

```
ps.setInt(1, theID);
```

As a side note, you should not need to include a semicolon at the end of your delete statement when making the call from JDBC.

Comment: it is string type

Comment: Then parse it into an int, and bind that int to the statement, see my answer above.

Comment: i have parsed and removed the semi colon but still cannot delete

Comment: `but still cannot delete` ... that's not an actionable comment.  Are you getting an error?  Are you not getting an error?  What is happening?

Comment: my program can run and i can select a row form my tableview in the GUI but when i press DELETE button it gives error and does not delete the selected row the program doesn not crash but the delete function does not apply to the tableview

Comment: `it gives error` ... again, _what_ is the error message?

Comment: it gives more than 100 errors first few are:at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java

Comment: @dedicated I don't know much about JavaFX.  The JDBC code I gave you is valid and should not be causing errors.  Is there any chance your code has some other problems?

Comment: the only problem is selecting the id from the tableview my tableview has 7 columns one of them being id, i am confused on the actual syntax to select the data

Comment: I have given the best answer which comes to mind.  If you can steer me in the right direction, I'm happy to answer something else.

Comment: Post your complete `stacktrace` in your question like you would post code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am guessing that the user is not having a problem deleting from the database, but is having a problem deleting from the `TableView`.

Comment: @Sedrick Depending on his SQL version, the `DELETE` query itself could very well have also been wrong.  There may be two questions happening here at the same time.

Comment: We will not know for sure until the user explains the problem better and post the full stacktrace. The user seems to not want to put in the effort to get the best answer.